# How to throw an error with transaction java

Tags: java, exception

I'm doing something like this:

```
try {
            client.restoreFromClusterSnapshot(req);
        } catch (AmazonRedshiftException e) {
            txUtils.execute((ts) -> {
                redshiftDto.setStatus(ResourceStatus.FAILED);
                redshiftDto.setStatusDetails(e.getMessage());
                redshiftDto.setUpdatedOn(Timestamp.from(Instant.now()));
                this.rdao.merge(redshiftDto);
                return null;
            });
            LOGGER.error("CANNOT START REDSHIFT- " + e.getErrorMessage());
            throw new AmazonRedshiftException( "CANNOT START REDSHIFT- "
              + e.getErrorMessage());

        }
```

In this code, I'm not able to set database variable if I'm throwing an error because it is terminating my transaction. If I'll comment that throw it will work and my database value will be set. But I'll not able to throw anything. How can I do both- (throwing and setting value in DB)

Comment: That should probably be due to `txUtils` reacting to the Exception that you throw, throw an exception the `txUtils` doesn't handle. Also, please specify what class `txUtils`belongs to.

Comment: why must you execute that transaction there instead of in the point where you're handling that exception anyways?

Comment: Try to debug the code, this will help you to check what txUtils is actually doing, is control is coming back to line of your code "throw new AmazonRedshiftException..."??

Comment: I'm executing that transaction because if restoreFromClusterSnapshot failed then it should set FAILED as status of redshift in db and i will able to show it as Failed in UI by throwing it i will let UI to show the error

Answer (score 0):

What I'd do is make use of the `finally` clause.

```
AmazonRedshiftException exception = null;
try {
    cluster = client.restoreFromClusterSnapshot(req);
} catch (AmazonRedshiftException e) {
    exception = e;
    LOGGER.error("CANNOT START REDSHIFT- " + e.getErrorMessage());
    throw new AmazonRedshiftException( "CANNOT START REDSHIFT- "
          + e.getErrorMessage());
} finally {
    if(exception != null) {
        txUtils.execute((ts) -> {
            redshiftDto.setStatus(ResourceStatus.FAILED);
            redshiftDto.setStatusDetails(exception.getMessage());
            redshiftDto.setUpdatedOn(Timestamp.from(Instant.now()));
            this.rdao.merge(redshiftDto);
            return null;
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: this can be used. But initialize AmazonRedshiftException then use it, lines are getting more. Can we use something like making BaseException class then throw it